Trying to pull the first word from a text file that has a username password format and pass it to a command
I have a text file. It appears similar to this:
john-doe password
I want to pull the username from the list and use it to add the user to a group:
net localgroup "remote desktop users" username /add
I have another batch file that successfully reads the list and creates an account:
@For /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "\192.168.99.100\SetupPC\staff.txt"') do (net user %%a /add /Y)
How would I modify this to only use the first word (username)?
